# Lucene indexing with restricted user access

Tags: solr, lucene, full-text-search, search-engine, searchview

We are trying to add full text search capabilities to our custom knowledge Base using lucene respectively solr. We currently restrict what a user can see with a role based model. So there is an array of roles attached to each article and if a user is also a member of one of that roles he / she can view the article.

So of course the search should only return results the user has access to.

I am a bit stuck on where to start or how to do this. Do I need to filter the results later? Do I create a role based index?

It would be highly appreciated if someone can point me in the right direction.

Thanks. Stephanie.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would advice storing the access roles as metadata. Let define `access_roles` is able to multi-valued string field.

```
access_roles:[user, admin] // Users and the Admin roles can access this search.
access_roles:[user, admin, anonymous] // Users and the Admin and Anonymous roles can access this search.
```

You should edit access roles when you want to change permissions.

---

When Users who have user role searches, solr will retrieve only the results that match the user's access role.

When User who have (`user`) role and also (`admin`) role searches, him searches go like:

```
q=mainquery
&fq=access_roles:user
&fq=access_roles:admin
&facet=on
&facet.field=access_roles
```

which fetches all result which contains `user` role **OR** `admin` role in `access_roles`;

When user, (`user`) role, member of a special team (`it_department`) role searches,

```
q=mainquery
&fq=access_roles:user
&fq=access_roles:it_department
&facet=on
&facet.field=access_roles
```

which fetches 'it_department' documents also

I have drawed authorization scheme for better understand

[image]

Queries adapted from http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SimpleFacetParameters#Multi-Select_Faceting_and_LocalParams

Comment: Hello. Thanks for your reply. Two questions, though. First wouldn't it be a bit dangerous only to restrict results based on the query? As I understand it, this query could be manipulated by the user. Second thing is, that we have implemented the access method as an interface so other implementations use different functions / methods. As I just was told we have one organisation who for example uses the up address to restrict access. So basically the access_method needs to return true in real time per user session. Thanks. Stephanie

Comment: I didn't think your solr query directly accessible from last users.I considered you are using web framework. I think you should take query from user in web project sth like Spring with lucene query parser. Than you should define some constants to implemented access_roles that constant able to differentiate all access groups. Namely you can not use boolean directly. You should define indicator that is implemented user group specific. And if access method is true you should add access_role to query with intercepting user accessible controller methods. Solr doesn't have any authorization framewor

Comment: framework that is why you should use spring like web framework. Because of search authorization. If solr server does not accessible directly from user and you manage solr with web framework I think you will solve your problem and search secured.